# Appharbor Background worker Issue - Error : "Terminated with exitcode -2147467259"

Tags: backgroundworker, appharbor

I have hosted 1 background worker on app-harbor for sending email. From last 3 to 4 days it is not working, I am getting error “Terminated with exitcode -2147467259”.

Below is script using in background worker:

static void Main(string[] args)

```
    {



        while (true)

        {

            //Worker_Process_For Send Email

            EmailCls.SendEmail_ByMailGun("a@b.com", "a@b.com", "Testing Shailesh-live", "body-live");



        }
```

}

public static IRestResponse SendEmail_MailGun(string from ,string to ,string subject,string body)

```
{

    RestClient client = new RestClient();

    client.BaseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailgun_baseurl"].ToString();// "https//api.mailgun.net/v2";



    client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailgun_key"].ToString());



    var mailgun_domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailgun_domain"].ToString();



    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

    request.AddParameter(mailgun_domain,mailgun_domain, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

    request.Resource = "{" + mailgun_domain + "}/messages";



    request.AddParameter("from", from);

    request.AddParameter("to", to);

    request.AddParameter("subject", subject);

    request.AddParameter("html", body);

    request.Method = Method.POST;

    return client.Execute(request);

}
```

The given script working fine in local machine but not  from appharbor .

Answer (score 0):

We recently added [a new logging module](http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/07/01/introducing-realtime-logging) which gives you real-time access to your background worker's STDOUT and STDERR.

You can start a log session by clicking the "Logging" link in the application's nav bar. That should give you more output to help identify and resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just Changed application Start Object[ which was not set in past ]in  Application property window and  rebuild and hosted it on app-harbor and my application started working f9.